# Linux partitioned for 8GB SSD + HDD?

Tags: linux, partitioning, ssd

I have a computer with 8GB of SSD storage, plus 1TB of regular hard-drive. I want to put the core of my Linux system in the SSD drive.

I'll be mounting `/home` in the second drive, but what other partitions should I set up that way? How can I avoid running out of space, say, if I install something that stores data as root such as `mongodb` or `postgresql`?

What's the best layout to take advantage of the SSD drive?

Comment: It would depend where you want to get the performance gains.  What is the linux machine doing?  If you want fast boots, then having the main OS components on the SSD would help. If you want fast DB access, then the database files should go on the SSD.

Comment: Are you sure the SSD is a separately-addressable device? It may simply be an automatically-managed cache that's part of the hard drive. If that's the case, no action is needed; the drive will do all the work for you to optimize performance.

Comment: You can always try short-stroking the drive to increase its performance. http://superuser.com/questions/57938/what-is-the-recommended-boot-partition-size-for-windows-7/324462#324462

Answer (score 0):

With only 8GB of SSD space, I would save it for your databases.

Store `mongodb` data on the SSD by using the `--db-path` parameter, and specify the non-default mount location: `mongod --db-path /mnt/ssd/mongo-data`